# Images are not visible on AMP pages

Tags: amp-html

I have implemented AMP on my home page, but some images are not visible.

You can check on our website :  https://www.hopohomes.com/

Comment: It doesn't appear to be a valid AMP page. You might want to try [Google's AMP validator](https://search.google.com/test/amp).

Answer (score 1):

I think u misunderstood about AMP concept.AMP-HTML tags are not the HTML tags replacement. 
You cant just convert your site into an AMP just by replacing few tags.
your site must follow amp html specification(https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/spec).

To test that, you can install amp validator chrome extension or by ending your site url by /#development=1 and look into your console.

Here is how it works,
google crawler will search for amp  in mobile search, if it is found and validates without error then your amp page may show up via link(not your main Web page) in rich search result and top stories in mobile.It will be very fast compared to normal pages but restrictive while developing.
https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/enhance-amp

If you are not willing to keep separate pages for AMP and non AMP(which is recommended to keep),then you need to compromise on your functionalities and also,
As of now you are having more than 100 errors which needs to be fixed in order for google to recognize.